# How To Cancel a neo4j Cypher Transaction

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I issue a number of CYPHER statements as part of a transaction. Transactions normally fail if an update operation fails for some underlying infrastructure reason, but how can I force a transaction to fail based on the criteria in my data. eg. Perform the transaction unless n.color = 'blue'?

Comment: Throw an exception yourself?

Comment: rollback ?  (you should say which language/driver you use)

Comment: i suppose it's techinically a rollback. javascript and bolt protocol.

Comment: I see this conversation (https://github.com/brikteknologier/seraph/issues/167). It seems that transactions cannot be rolled back manually... only in the event of a failure which is outside the scope of the query... https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/http-api/

Comment: Of course you can rollback a transaction ! If you look at the cited issue, it's because it's not the transaction endpoint. Take a look at the documentation here to see how to do it : https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/drivers/sessions-transactions/